# Jquery wysiwyg editor remove formatting plugin (rmFormat) not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jwysiwyg

I've downloaded and implemented the following plugin:
https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg

Now I don't want users to be able to format the text entered into the plugin, just basic bold itallics and paragraphs. So I've **tried** to implement the [rmFormat](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg/blob/master/plugins/wysiwyg.rmFormat.js) plugin

```
$('textarea.wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
        brIE: true,
        rmUnusedControls: true,
        controls: {
            bold: { visible: true },
            italic: { visible: true },
            h3: { visible: true },
            removeFormat: { visible: true }
        },
        rmUnwantedBr: false,
        plugins: {
            rmFormat: {
                rmMsWordMarkup: true,
                enabled:true
            }
        }
    });
```

But well it just doesn't work! anyone any experience of this? If not anyone got any other suggestions of controls like this that allow very simple markup control only?

Site is **MVC** btw

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KjVEt/69/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liam , i have used this plugins and faced the same problems.So i have to write some custom code and it worked for me.

I have written code in **jquery.jwysiwyg.js** file

```
 this.removeFormat = function () {
         ...
      // Get the current html strings from textarea
         var newContent = this.getContent();
        // it will remove all the html formatting applied on textarea
         newContent = newContent.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/gi, '');
         // update new contents on textarea
         this.editorDoc.body.innerHTML = newContent;
         this.saveContent();

 return this;
}
```

Comment: I give in, this is a lost cause! Ta for trying!